# How do i create instace of backbone collection outside of script

Tags: php, javascript, backbone.js

I have my backbone collection named "Events" and model "Event". I like create backbone collection in that way .. 
Take a look to my code

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>js/backbone-calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    var events = new Events([],{ model : Event , url : 'event' });
    new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events}).render();
    events.fetch();
  });
</script>
```

In my PHP file i linked backbone-calendar.js where i wrote the backbone calendar application 
but i wanna create instance of Events in that way .... is it possible? thanks
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Why aren't `model` and `url` defined as part of `Events`? That's the usual way to do it. And `url` can be a function if it needs to change.

Comment: i want to use  my **backbone-calendar.js** script in multiple file. what if i wanna change my url to **todo** in another php file .

Comment: ["There are several options that, if provided, are attached to the collection directly: `url`, `model` and `comparator`."](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor) so that should work if `event` is the right `url`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question, but if you want to set "url" key from php:

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>js/backbone-calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    var events = new Events([],{ model : Event , url : '<?php echo event_url(); ?>' });
    new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events}).render();
    events.fetch();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer make me get some idea ..i try this way it help me . anyway thanks .
`var events = new Events([],{ model : Event , url :$('#url').html() .. ..`